Custom keycloak language
I'm running Keycloak 25.0.1. 
I have followed official Keycloak documentation. 
I have added all 3 themes to the mytheme folder, account, email and login.  
I see mytheme when I try to choose a theme from the list, but when I try to choose a Selected Locale there is no option for my languge.
There is a theme.properties file with: 
parent=base
supported-locales=en,fr,de,sr

Any idea what else am I missing with keycloak configuration or setup?

Issue is with theme.properties
The key supported-locales should be locales
